# Не удается реализовать функцию в Python из-за ошибки "Use a.any() or a.all()"

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

def xe(x):
    return x*np.exp(-x) #-3 3
def sin10(x):
    return np.sin(10*x) #-10 10
def xe_e_sin(x):
    return x*np.exp(-0.1*x*x) + np.exp(-0.1*(x-5)*(x-5))*np.sin(10*x) #-10 10

def choose(p):
    if p==1:
        return xe(x1)
    if p==2:
        return sin10(x1)
    if p==3:
        return xe_e_sin(x1)


print("Введите промежуток Х1 и Х2")
X1=int(input())
X2=int(input())
print("Введите значение N")
N=int(input())
h=(X2-X1)/N
print("Наш шаг:")
print(h)

print("Если вы хотите посчитать xe^(-x) Введите 1")
print("Если вы хотите посчитать sin(10x) Введите 2")
print("Если вы хотите посчитать xe^(-0.1x^2)+e^(-0.1(x-5)^2)sin(10x) Введите 3")
p=int(input())
ZN_X=[]
ZN_Y=[]
x1=X1
x2=X2

while (x1<=x2+0.1):
    ZN_X.append(x1)
    ZN_Y.append(choose(p))
    x1+=h
#print(ZN_X, ZN_Y)
Znacheniya_F=pd.DataFrame({"Значение Х":ZN_X,"Значение Y":ZN_Y})
print(Znacheniya_F)

def progonka(N,A,B):
    z = np.empty([N])
    eps = np.zeros([N])
    X = np.empty([N]) 
    et = np.zeros([N])
    n = (N-1)
    eps[0]=-A[0][1]/A[0][0]
    et[0]=B[0]/A[0][0]
    for i in range(1,n):
        z=A[i][i]+A[i][i-1]*eps[i-1]
        eps[i]=-A[i][i+1]/z
        et[i]=(B[i]-A[i][i-1]*et[i-1])/z
    X[n]= (B[n]-A[n][n-1]*et[n-1])/(A[n][n]+A[n][n-1]*eps[n-1])
    for i in range(n-1,0,-1):
        X[i]= eps[i]*X[i+1]+et[i]
    X[0] = eps[0]*X[1]+et[0]
    return X

A = np.eye(N+1)
for i in range(1,N):
    A[i][i] +=3
    A[i][i-1]+=1
    A[i][i+1]+=1

m=[]
m0=(ZN_Y[1]-ZN_Y[0])/h
m.append(m0)
i=1
while i<=((N-1)):
    m.append((ZN_Y[i+1]-ZN_Y[i-1])*(3/h))
    i+=1
mN=(ZN_Y[N]-ZN_Y[N-1])/h
m.append(mN)
print(m)

mk=progonka(N+1,A,m)
print(mk)

x=X1
k=0
x1=X1
x2=X2
fk=[]
print(x,x1,x2)
d = 10
H = h*1/p
X = ([])
S3 = ([])
for i in range(N):
    X.append(ZN_X[i])
    S3.append(ZN_Y[i])
    for k in range(1,d):
        x = ZN_X[i] + H * k
        t = (x - ZN_X[i]) / h
        u1 = (t-1)*(t-1)*(2*t+1)
        u2 = t*t*(3-2*t)
        u3 = t*(1-t)*(1-t)     
        u4 = t*t*(t-1)
        X.append(x)
        S3.append(u1*ZN_Y[i] + u2*ZN_Y[i+1] + u3*mk[i]*h + u4*mk[i+1]*h)  
X.append(ZN_X[-1])
S3.append(ZN_Y[-1])

H = h/100
xk = np.arange(-10,10+H,H)
fk.append(choose(xk))
Znacheniya_S=pd.DataFrame({"Значение Х":X,"Значение S3":S3})
print(fk)
#print(Znacheniya_S)
plt.plot(xk, fk, 'r',linewidth=1.5, label='График Функции') 
#plt.show()
plt.plot(X, S3, "k",linewidth=1.5,label="Построенный сплайн") 
plt.show()
```

Не могу использовать свою заданную функцию choose()
Выдает ошибку

> The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.
>   Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: вот тут у вас явно странное использование функции fk.append(choose(xk)) - вы отдаете массив в качестве аргумента, а функция ждет int

Comment: @splash58 но если передать choose(1) все заработает, но только для  первой функции и одного элемента, а мне надо прогнать весь массив

Comment: сделайте массив вторым аргументом, выбор все равно должен быть

Comment: @splash58, немного не понял. Можете написать, как должно быть?

Comment: def choose(p,x1):  и соответственно перепишите вызовы

Comment: @splash58, спасибо, заработало